# Can a Google App be configured to run on a device level (Chromebook)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I'm attempting to develop an app and from my understanding of Google domains apps are pushed out under `Device Management->Chrome Devices->User Settings->Managed Force Installed Apps`.

These apps run when the user is signed in. Is there a way to deploy an app that runs whenever the device is powered on, whether signed in or not?

I'm essentially designing a simple app that sends "heartbeats" to a server whenever it's connected. The Chromebooks will have management licenses and be enrolled in the domain.

Comment: Perhaps you should make clear wether **public session** or **kiosk-mode** are options, or if you need users to log in normally but have process run before anyone is logged in.

Comment: @DanSut - When you say public session, I assume you mean guest.  If a user is required to be active, I would like my app to be running even when the user is in Kiosk mode (for another app).  I basically want my app to send data whether or a user is logged in, running a kiosk app, or even browsing as a guest.  I essentially want the app to always run on a per-device basis as opposed to per user

Comment: I still think you need to edit to clarify your Q for a good answer. [Public Session](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3017014?hl=en) isn't same as Guest, similar but not the same. If this works for you then you can set one to auto-launch in Device Settings and force install apps, including one with your background behavior, in Public Session settings. If you want to auto-launch a Kiosk app then your background behavior belongs in Kiosk app code as I understand. If you want the sign-on screen to appear then I have not yet found a (non-dev) way of running stuff while at sign-on screen.